# Кадр не находится в модуле

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl2

Пишу небольшой движок на C++ с SDL2 и графикой OpenGL. Писал код, всё было нормально, но вчера вдруг начала появляться такая вот ошибка.

Кадр не находится в модуле

Текущий кадр стека не найден в загруженном модуле. Исходный код не может быть показан для этого расположения.
[image: Кадр не находится в модуле]

Появляется она как-то рандомно, иногда программа запускается, но чаще всего выкидывает эту ошибку. Также заметил, что перед запуском программа ждёт 2-3 секунды, а потом резко начинает работать (открывает окно, рендерит графику). Не помню, чтобы такое было раньше.
Я пытался понять, что происходит, пробовал отключать написанный недавно код, но она продолжила появляться. Пишу в Visual Studio 2017.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким?

Comment: Там же написано, исключение: нарушение доступа. Такое ощущение что вы вызвали функцию через битый указатель. Ищите ошибки в своем коде.

Comment: Ваша проблема не в кадре стека, а в **нарушении прав доступа при исполнении**

Comment: Хм, сейчас буду всё пересматривать...